# How can I insert multiple rows into a table with react-native-sqlite-storage?

Tags: sqlite, react-native, react-native-sqlite-storage

In the react-native-sqlite-storage's tests (see https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage/blob/master/test/index.ios.promise.js#L141-L149) I find:

```
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Employees (name, office, department) VALUES ("Sylvester Stallone", 2,  4);');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Employees (name, office, department) VALUES ("Elvis Presley", 2, 4);');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Employees (name, office, department) VALUES ("Leslie Nelson", 3,  4);');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Employees (name, office, department) VALUES ("Fidel Castro", 3, 3);');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Employees (name, office, department) VALUES ("Bill Clinton", 1, 3);');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Employees (name, office, department) VALUES ("Margaret Thatcher", 1, 3);');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Employees (name, office, department) VALUES ("Donald Trump", 1, 3);');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Employees (name, office, department) VALUES ("Dr DRE", 2, 2);');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Employees (name, office, department) VALUES ("Samantha Fox", 2, 1);');
```

Is there a way to do this with one statement by passing an array?

Answer (score 8):

Assuming that myDb is your connection variable :

```
const myDb=SQLite.openDatabase({name:"yourDb", createFromLocation:"yourDB.db"}, ()=>console.log('DB opened'), (err)=>alert('error : ' + err));
```

If you want to insert three rows into your "Employees" table :

```
myDb.transaction((tx)=>{
  tx.executeSql(        
    'INSERT INTO Employees (name,office,departement) VALUES (?,?,?),(?,?,?),(?,?,?)',
    ['Sylvester Stallone',2,4,'Elvis Presley',2,4,'Leslie Nelson',3,4],
    (tx, results) => {               
      if (results.rowsAffected > 0 ) {
        console.log('Insert success');              
      } else {
        console.log('Insert failed');
      }
    }
  );
});
```

Good luck!

Comment: Is there any limit on number of rows that can be inserted?

Comment: Honestly, @Kunal, i dont know. i haven't yet try inserting a very large amount of rows.